# Equation numbering below gathering, no matter how far left the equation is shifted

Tags: equations, gather

Code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{beamer}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{pgfpages}
\pgfpagesuselayout{resize to}[a4paper,landscape]
%\pgfpagesuselayout{2 on 1}[a4paper]
%\usetheme{Singapore}
\usetheme{Boadilla}
\usepackage{bm}
%\usefonttheme[?options?]{structuresmallcapsserif}
%\definecolor{beamer@blendedblue}{RGB}{203,140,55} % changed this
\definecolor{beamer@blendedblue}{RGB}{0,102,102} % changed this
%\definecolor{beamer@blendedblue}{RGB}{0,153,153} % changed this
\usefonttheme{professionalfonts} %To get the accents aligned correctly, albeit in Computer Modern Roman
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\setbeamertemplate{blocks}[rounded][shadow=true]
\begin{document}
    %-----------------------------------------------------------------New slide ----------------------------------------------------%
    \begin{frame}{Sample}
        \setcounter{equation}{100}
        \begin{gather}
            \mathbf{x}\left(t_0\right) = \mathbf{x}_0,\\
            \hspace{-1.5pt}
            \left[\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial\mathbf{x}} + \left(\frac{\partial \bm{\Psi}}{\partial \mathbf{x}}\right)^{\hspace{-0.17cm}\textrm{T}}\bm{\nu} - \bm{\lambda}\right]^{\hspace{-0.1cm}\textrm{T}}_{\hspace{-0.1cm}*,t_f}\hspace{-0.2cm}\delta\mathbf{x}_f + \left[\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial t} + \left(\frac{\partial \bm{\Psi}}{\partial t}\right)^{\hspace{-0.17cm}\textrm{T}}\bm{\nu} + \mathcal{H}\right]_{\hspace{-0.1cm}*,t_f}\hspace{-0.2cm}\delta t_f = 0.
            \hspace{1000pt minus 1fill}\\
            \bm{\Psi}\left(\mathbf{x}\left(t_f\right), t_f\right) = \mathbf{0}.
        \end{gather}
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Output:
[image]

No matter how far I shift the middle equation (202), the equation label will always appear slightly below. Is there a way to align that equation label with the middle equation?

Comment: `\hspace{1000pt minus 1fill}` is ensuring the natural width of that row is very large so will force the equation number to move

Comment: Oh, ok, got it, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You were adding 1000pt to the width of that row so it was always going to be too large.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{beamer}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{pgfpages}
\pgfpagesuselayout{resize to}[a4paper,landscape]
%\pgfpagesuselayout{2 on 1}[a4paper]
%\usetheme{Singapore}
\usetheme{Boadilla}
\usepackage{bm}
%\usefonttheme[?options?]{structuresmallcapsserif}
%\definecolor{beamer@blendedblue}{RGB}{203,140,55} % changed this
\definecolor{beamer@blendedblue}{RGB}{0,102,102} % changed this
%\definecolor{beamer@blendedblue}{RGB}{0,153,153} % changed this
\usefonttheme{professionalfonts} %To get the accents aligned correctly, albeit in Computer Modern Roman
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\setbeamertemplate{blocks}[rounded][shadow=true]
\begin{document}
    %-----------------------------------------------------------------New slide ----------------------------------------------------%
    \begin{frame}{Sample}
        \setcounter{equation}{100}
        \begin{gather}
            \mathbf{x}\left(t_0\right) = \mathbf{x}_0,\\
            \hspace*{-15pt}
            \left[\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial\mathbf{x}} + \left(\frac{\partial \bm{\Psi}}{\partial \mathbf{x}}\right)^{\hspace{-0.17cm}\textrm{T}}\bm{\nu} - \bm{\lambda}\right]^{\hspace{-0.1cm}\textrm{T}}_{\hspace{-0.1cm}*,t_f}\hspace{-0.4cm}\delta\mathbf{x}_f + \left[\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial t} + \left(\frac{\partial \bm{\Psi}}{\partial t}\right)^{\hspace{-0.17cm}\textrm{T}}\bm{\nu} + \mathcal{H}\right]_{\hspace{-0.1cm}*,t_f}\hspace{-0.5cm}\delta t_f = 0.
            \\
            \bm{\Psi}\left(\mathbf{x}\left(t_f\right), t_f\right) = \mathbf{0}.
        \end{gather}
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: What does the asterisk in `\hspace*` do?

Comment: hspace* is space that is not dropped at the start of a line

Comment: When I put `\hspace*{-0.9cm}` in place of `\hspace{-0.9cm}`, the result is the same. Under which circumstance will I be able to see the difference?

Comment: @Superman yes it is here, but the * does no harm, try it at the start of a text line.